# How to set the Bash python env and vim python env paths the same?

Tags: bash, python

When I check for python version in vim file, it displays 3.6 whereas it shows python 3.7 when I check from the bash terminal. As a result, when I pip install  from the terminal, it installs in the python 3.7 path. So, when I run my python vim file, the package isn't detected.

How do I change the python vim file to point at the same python version as my Bash terminal does?

My linux server has python 3.6 and python 3.7 installed. My vim file accesses the python 3.6 from this dir `/home/$USER/anaconda3/envs/$USER/lib/python3.6` i.e., `sys.path` gives the path directory as below.

```
['/home/$USER/codes', '/cm/local/apps/cuda/libs/current/pynvml', '/home/$USER/anaconda3/envs/$USER/lib/python36.zip', '/home/$USER/anaconda3/envs/$USER/lib/python3.6', '/home/$USER/anaconda3/envs/$USER/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/$USER/anaconda3/envs/$USER/lib/python3.6/site-packages'
```

But, when I run python from bash terminal, it uses python 3.7 and `sys.path` gives the path directory as below.

```
['', '/cm/local/apps/cuda/libs/current/pynvml', '/home/$USER/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip', '/home/$USER/anaconda3/lib/python3.7', '/home/$USER/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/$USER/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

How do I change the vim path directory to be the same as Bash terminal as all the `pip install <module>` from bash are stored for python 3.7 in the latter directory?

Comment: Interesting. This is the third time in three days that someone has asked a question about Python version in Vim.  Did you look for related subject matter here before posting? If not search the site for newer posts containing "python version" and that should get you there.

Comment: @BLayer Which one are you referring to?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!